# Reversing Arduino mega bytecode

Tags: arduino

I have an hex dump of the 256k of my arduino mega's flash memory.

I do not understand where is the bootloader. I see at 0x0000 address an interupt vector for reset but i do not understand how the bootloaders jumps to the main program.

Is there a way to identity `setup()` and `loop()` functions addresses?

Comment: there must be the way, but how do you suppose to get the answer without providing the binary?

Comment: Examining the ATmega1280 datasheet and comparison with Arduino Mega memory mapping may be a solution.